# talk about angularjs structure - how to reduce libs in index.html

Tags: angularjs

As we know, angular is a good MVC framework to build your application with single page, but I'm afraid that if taking too much work in one page, will it be a problem to load lots of javascript libs in index.html? some issue like loading slowly or even performance/network issue.

As my demo below, there's lots of js libs, and about the '`test/restful/restful.js'`, I want to load it when my router goes to restful.html, but I need to declare the controller in router, in index.html, otherwise the '`RestfulCtrl`' cannot be recognized by angular lifecycle, so how to separate resources to reduce the work of `index.html`, or it is the common defect of single page MVC
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The size of your controller is tiny compared to the size of all the libraries (jquery, angular, etc.) you're already loading. Having one HTTP request for each and every controller or service JS file is obviously not a good idea, but you should simply concatenate and minify those at build time, and have a single JS file to load that contains your whole application. So

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="FirstCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="SecondCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="FirstService.js"></script>
<script src="SecondService.js"></script>
```

should become

```
<script src="myCompleteApp.min.js"></script>
```

You can also choose to concatenate all the libraries and your own minified application into a single big file if you prefer, which would allow loading a single big JS file containing everything, in a single HTTP request.

Grunt and Gulp are the two main tools used to do that.

Comment: so you mean if the restful.js only used in the restful.html, i need to load it in index.html ? no other way ?

Comment: No, there's no other supported way in the current version of angular.